# reactjs cant modify a bound value

Tags: reactjs

I am using reactjs with a parent and a child component.  In the child, I am binding the value of a textarea to a property sent in by the parent.  When I remove the child component by clicking the 'remove' button, the value of the textarea matches the inner html text on the div of the child component, as expected.  However, because the textarea's value is bound to the reactjs property, I am unable to modify the contents of the text area.

I want to be able to change the value of the text area, save, and still have the child components delete correctly.  I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't seem to figure it out...

```
 //Child
    var Comment = React.createClass({
        remove: function () {
            this.props.deleteFromBoard(this.props.index)
        },
        save: function () {
            var val = this.refs.newText.value;
            console.log('New Comment: ' + val);
            this.props.updateCommentText(val, this.props.index);
            this.setState({editing:false})
        },
       render: function () {
           return (
               <div className="commentContainer">
                   <div className="commentText">{this.props.myVal}</div>
                   <textarea ref="newText"
                             value={this.props.myVal}
                             onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea>
                   <button onClick={this.save} className="button-success">save</button>
                   <button onClick={this.remove} className="button-danger">Remove Question</button>
               </div>
           );
       }
   });

   //Parent
   var Board = React.createClass({
       //Initial state is an array with three different strings of text 'comments'
       getInitialState: function(){
           return {
               comments: [
                   'One',
                   'Two',
                   'Three',
                   'Four'
               ]
           }
       },
       removeComment: function(i){
           console.log('Removing comment: ' + i + ' bkbk');
           var arr = this.state.comments;
           //Spicing the array (where do you want to start? 'i', how many do you want to remove? '1'
           arr.splice(i,1);
           this.setState({comments:arr})
       },
       reportMe: function(){
           var arr = this.state.comments;
           var arrayLength = arr.length;
           for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                 alert(arr[i]);
           }
       },
       updateComment: function(newText, i){
            var arr = this.state.comments;
            arr[i] = newText
            this.setState({comments:arr})
        },
       //Properties of each comment
       eachComment: function(text, i) {
           return (
               <Comment
                   key={i} index={i} myVal={text} updateCommentText={this.updateComment} deleteFromBoard={this.removeComment}></Comment>

           );
       },
        render: function(){
            return (
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.reportMe.bind(null)} className="button-success">Report Contents Of Array</button>
                    <div className="board">
                       {
                           this.state.comments.map(this.eachComment)
                       }
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
   })
   ReactDOM.render(<Board/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Try using `defaultValue` instead of `value` with your textarea - [controlled components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Comment: Tried defaultValue.  It does not keep the value of the textarea in sync when you delete a child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this  :

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
     return {
        myVal : this.props.myVal || '',
     }
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps){
         if(this.state.myVal !== nextProps.myVal){
             this.setState({myVal : nextProps.myVal});
          }
    },
    handleChange : function(event){ 
        this.setState({
            myVal : event.target.value,
        });
        ...
    },
    ....
    save: function () {
        var val = this.state.myVal;
        console.log('New Comment: ' + val);
        this.props.updateCommentText(val, this.props.index);
        this.setState({editing:false})
    },
     render: function(){
       (
           <div className="commentContainer">
               <div className="commentText">{this.props.myVal}</div>
               <textarea ref="newText"
                         value={this.state.myVal} <-- state.myVal instead of props.myVal
                         onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
               </textarea>
               <button onClick={this.save.bind(this)} className="button-success">save</button>
               <button onClick={this.remove.bind(this)} className="button-danger">Remove Question</button>
           </div>
       );
     }

   }
});
```

Comment: You NAILED IT!!!!!!!!  Thank You so much!!!!  I struggled for a LONG time on that.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please explain this function does?   'componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps)'

Comment: Here is the doc : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops